# Visual Basic - Progress bar with RichTextBox and timer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a timer with progress bar and richtextbox.
If % then print an loading info.

I've got:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 15 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading jakiśtam2.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 25 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading jakiśtam4.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 45 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading 7567567..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 55 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading Lollol.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 80 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Można wpisywać co się chce" & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 86 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "BlaBlabla" & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 95 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Make-cash.pl" & vbCrLf
    End Sub
```

But it's not working. I'm getting and error:
    End of statement expected.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub MephProgressBar2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MephProgressBar2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub MephButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MephButton1.Click
        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 15 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading jakiśtam2.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 25 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading jakiśtam4.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 45 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading 7567567..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 55 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Loading Lollol.dll..." & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 80 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Można wpisywać co się chce" & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 86 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "BlaBlabla" & vbCrLf
        If MephProgressBar2.Value = 95 Then RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & "Make-cash.pl" & vbCrLf

    End Sub
End Class
```

Please help, i'm newbie in vb

Comment: @GrantWinney changed to more readable

Comment: @MarkusMaleńki it's still not valid VB.Net the body of the `if` and the `end if` should be on their own lines. Or if you want to do a `if` in a single line. You need to remove the `End If`

Comment: @litelite here is all of the code of app: https://pastebin.com/4PavTxUg
I deleted End If and not an error, but after click on button nothing happen

Comment: @MarkusMaleńki So you can run it? then it's not a End Of Statement Expected error?!

Comment: @litelite When i deleted end if it's opening but nothing happend after clicking on button

Comment: @MarkusMaleńki So the error changed. Are you sure the timer is started? And that you are changing the value of the progress bar?

Comment: You are relying on the value of the progress bar, which you never increment.  Use RichTextBox1.AppendText("...") to add information to a RichTextBox control.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Four questions with 9 answers but none accepted.  Accepting answers helps others find good answers even if you cant post answers yourself

Comment: How is your progress bar value being changed? Your pastebin does not show it.